# How to rename data frame variables as x1, x2, ... in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, rename

I know there's a simple solution, but I keep getting error messages. Given this sample data frame:

```
y <- c(1,2,3)
a <- c(2,4,6)
b <- c(4,8,12)
c <- c(8,16,24)
z <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,a,b,c))
z
  y a  b  c
1 1 2  4  8
2 2 4  8 16
3 3 6 12 24
```

I'd like an automated piece of code that renames column 2 to x1, column 3 to x2, and column 3 to x3. I've attempted:

```
for (i in 2:4){ x=colnames(z[i]); rename(z, c(x=paste("x",i,sep=""))) }
```

and

```
apply(z[,2:4], 2, function(x) rename(z, c(x=paste("x",i,sep="")))  )
```

but no success. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop

```
 names(z)[-1] <- paste0('x', 1:(ncol(z)-1))
```

EDIT: Added @Pierre Lafortune's suggestion

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I'm familiar with the names() function, but what is the "[-1]" part doing?

Comment: I had `names(z)[-1] <- paste0('x', 1:(ncol(z)-1))` just in case the real dataset was bigger. But it's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @RobertF `names(z)` will give all the column names from the first to the last.  By doing `names(z)[-1]` we are omitting the first column from consideration.

Comment: As a followup, it's also possible to choose a sequence of variable names to rename - for example in the z data frame above, we can rename "a" to "x1" and "b" to "x2" and ignore "y" and "c": `names(z)[-1][-3] <- paste0('x', 1:2)`.

Comment: You can try `names(z)[-c(1,4)] <- paste0('x', 1:2)`